# Firefox HTML5 Video overlay Text with position absolute and max z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    .overlayFull {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: 2147483647;
        color: #ff9800;
        opacity: .5;
    }

document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", changeScreen, false);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", changeScreen, false);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", changeScreen, false);
```

So on fullscreen event I'm showing text overlay, it works on all browsers except firefox, any ideas? I have verified the function is called in firefox. All I am doing inside the changeScreen function is changing display from block/none.

Comment: Could you make a working https://jsfiddle.net/ or a snippet in your post(`< >` button) so your code is easier to test?

Comment: first thing you need to know is that you cannot overlay text on full screen video, only in 'kiosk mode' e.g. when the browser window is on full screen mode itself but the video element remains in the document flow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TcpX5/36/ as you can see it works in all browsers but not firefox